# Displaying names using conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if I have a certain table, let's say table X
which contains salary and names, how would I display the maximum salary along with corresponding names?
Thank you.

Comment: you will have to create it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
select salary, name
from X
where salary = (select MAX(salary) from X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see this using `EMP` table example :

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT MAX(sal) max_sal FROM emp)
  3  SELECT ename, sal
  4  FROM emp
  5  WHERE sal = (SELECT max_sal FROM DATA)
  6  /

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
KING             5000

SQL>
```